# all menu item's become selectable

Tags: c#, menu, xna, position

I am trying to create a simple menu, the string that is selected changes colur as it is instructed to do, I just can't seem to space out each item in the string list on the Y axis, currently they are all positioned in the middle but at the top of the screen overlapping each other.  I know this is probably a very simple fix but I am a novice at XNA. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**MenuManagement Class**

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Game2
{
    class MenuManagement 
    {
        KeyboardState keyboard;
        KeyboardState prevKey;

        MouseState mouse;

        Vector2 position;

        List<String> buttonList = new List<string>();
        SpriteFont spriteFont;
        int selected = 0; 

        public MenuManagement ()
        {

            buttonList.Add("Play");
            buttonList.Add("Options");
            buttonList.Add("instructions");
            buttonList.Add("Exit");

        }


     private void MeasureMenu()
    {
        height = 0;
        width = 0;

         foreach (string item in buttonList)
         {
             Vector2 size = spriteFont.MeasureString(item);
             height += spriteFont.LineSpacing + 5;
         }
    }

        public void LoadContent (ContentManager Content )
        {
            spriteFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("spriteFont");          

        }

        public void Update (GameTime theGameTime)
        {

            keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();

            if (checkKeyBoard(Keys.Up))
            {
                if (selected > 0)
                {
                    selected--;
                }
            }

            if (checkKeyBoard(Keys.Down))
            {
                if (selected < buttonList.Count - 1)
                {
                    selected++;
                }
            }

            prevKey = keyboard;

        }

        public bool checkKeyBoard (Keys key)
        {
            return (keyboard.IsKeyDown(key) && prevKey.IsKeyDown(key)); 
        }

        public void Draw (SpriteBatch theSpriteBatch)
        {
            theSpriteBatch.Begin();
            Color color;


            for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Count; i++)
            {
                Vector2 location = position;
                if (i == selected)
                {
                    color = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else
                {
                    color = Color.Blue;
                }


        location.Y += spriteFont.LineSpacing + 5;
    }
           theSpriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[0], new Vector2 (300, 100), color);
    theSpriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[1], new Vector2(300, 150), color);
    theSpriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[2], new Vector2(300, 200), color);
    theSpriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[3], new Vector2(300, 250), color);
    theSpriteBatch.End();

        }

    }


}
```

**Game1**

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Game2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch theSpriteBatch;
        public static Rectangle screen;
        public static string GameState = "Menu";
        MenuManagement menuManagement;


        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }


        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            menuManagement = new MenuManagement();
            screen = new Rectangle(0, 0, graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
            base.Initialize();
        }


        protected override void LoadContent()
        {

            theSpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            menuManagement.LoadContent(Content);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

            protected override void UnloadContent()
            {
                // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
            }

 // <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();



 switch (GameState)
        {
            case "Menu":
                menuManagement.Update(gameTime);
                break;
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        switch (GameState)
        {
            case "Menu":
                menuManagement.Draw(theSpriteBatch);
                break;
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the length of the strings and place the next item where you want. You should look to SpriteFont.MeasureString().

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464128(v=xnagamestudio.30).aspx

To be clear, the reason they are overlapping is because you are putting them all in the same position:

```
Vector2 location = position;
```

and then:

```
new Vector2 (300, location.Y)
```

is where you are drawing the entire batch. You need to change the position of each of the menu items. The simplest fix is to increment the Y value of the location for each item. That will move the next menu item toward the bottom. Increment X to move right.

Comment: Hey Todd, I did have a look at the MeasureString, I just took it out for the time being, apologies for that, I've now included the method for the measure String. WIll have a look at the second part now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you attempting to stack your menu vertically or horizontally?

Comment: I have changed the position of the Y axis in the draw method, so they are all 50px underneath each other, the issue is that when I press down, all of them become highlighted. I am stacking them vertically.

Comment: Is that a new issue? I want to make sure we are making progress.

Comment: before, only one would get highlighted (as far as I'm aware as they were all stacked on top of each other) now they are all not selected and when I press the up or down arrow key they all become selected.

Comment: New issue. The problem is where you are keeping track of "selected". Put a break point inside the loop determining the color and you should see where the issue is. if not, post a little more detail, and probably in a new question since this original question has been answered.

Comment: If you are holding down the key, the Update method is checking several times per second, and you are likely just changing the menu items so fast, it looks like they are the same color.